# If we have a congruence a≡b (mod m), does it follow that a≡b(mod prime factor of m)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Consider `a≡b (mod m)`
By the divison lemma, `a = km+r (0<r<m)`

Consider `a≡b (mod p, a prime factor of m)`

By the division lemma, `a = gp + r' (0<r'<p)`

```
m = px (as a prime factor of m)


gp + r' = km + r
((gm)/x) + r' = km + r
m((g/x)-k) = r - r'
```

Now if the remainders were the same, then (g/x)-k = 0.
I'm not sure how to prove this, or where to go from here..

Comment: if $m\mid a-b$ and $p\mid m$, then $p\mid a-b$

Comment: You too, @hamam.  Note the difference $p|a$, vs. $p\mid a$,

Comment: Thanks, @J.W.Tanner

Comment: @amWhy Ok, Thank you. Next, i will do so.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Sorry I'm not too sure where to go still

Comment: $a\equiv b\pmod m\iff a-b=km$; now if $m=pq$, then $a-b=kqp$, so...

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the title question is yes.

$a\equiv b\pmod m\iff a-b=km$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z.$

Now if $m=pq$ for some $q\in\mathbb Z$, then $a-b=kqp=jp$ for some $j=kq\in\mathbb Z$,

so $a\equiv b\pmod p$.